# Would does this function which converts a char array to an int array not work?

Tags: c

This program is supposed to convert the array of chars (string) into an array of ints by subtracting 97 from their ascii value (the input should be lower case cause a has an ascii value of 97). So if i enter the string abcd i should get 0123 but instead I somehow get this: 012134513789. I can't figure out where the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void userEnter(int*pattern, int n);



int main(void)
{
int n, i;
printf("What is the length of the array: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int pattern[n];
printf("Enter the char array: ");
userEnter(pattern, n);
printf("The int array is: ");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
printf("%d",pattern[i]);
}
printf("\n");

}

void userEnter(int*pattern, int n)
{
    char input[n];
    scanf("%s", input);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        pattern[i] = input[i]-97;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use valid grammar and indent your code correctly.

Comment: You have a waiting buffer overflow in `scanf("%s", input);`, and if you enter more than `n-1` characters, you can cause such output by overwriting `n` in `main`. If you never enter more than `n-1` characters, it should work and does here.

Answer (score 1):

```
char input[n];
scanf("%s", &input);
```

should be

```
char input[n+1];
scanf("%s", input);
```

`input` is equivalent to `&input[0]`

You should also exit the for loop in `userEnter` when you encounter the nul character that ends the user-entered string.  e.g. with something like

```
char* p = input;
while (*p != '\0') {
    *pattern = (*p) - 'a';
    p++;
    pattern++;
}
```

As KingsIndian points out, you also need to increase the size of your `input` buffer.  At present, you overflow that buffer and overwrite the loop counter `i`;

Comment: Yes I see but even then the output is the same.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain some of the surprising output

Answer (score 1):

The length parameter `n` includes one character for null as well. So, if you input length for `n` 4 then you can only input 3 characters, for example `abc` because the 4th is for the null.

So you should change the declaration accordingly:

Change:

```
 char input[n];
```

to:

```
 char input[n+1];
```

Note that variable length arrays are allowed only since C99.